# Equality between side classes with a finite and infinite cyclic quotient group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G/H$ be a cyclic group and $a^kH \in G/H,$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I have a small doubt: if for some reason $a^k \in H,$ then $k = 0$ if $G/H$ is an infinite cyclic group? What if $|G/H| = n,$ then if $a^k \in H,$ that means $n \mid k?$

Comment: What does $a^kH \in H$ mean?  The usual notation would have both $a^kH$ and $H$ being subsets of $G$, and (unless you try very hard to make your group weird!) it's not going to happen that $a^kH \in H$.  Did you maybe mean $a^kH = H$?

Comment: Forgive me, I edited the question, but it's $a^k \in H$

Comment: What if $a\in H$?  Then $a^k\in H$ regardless.  And,  if the order of $G/H$ is $n$, then the order of $aH$ divides $n$, by Lagrange.

Comment: I suspect that by *side classes* you really mean [cosets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset). In my native Finnish the term coset has been translated to a composite word that, if translated back one piece at a time, would become *side class*. My experience is that such twists of terminology are rarely unique to Finnish :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By closure of $H$ (as a subgroup of $G$), if $a\in H$, then $a^m\in H$ for all $m\in\Bbb Z$.